# Is it possible to draw (show) whitespace (indention) in pure CSS?

Tags: css, whitespace

Is it possible to show whitespace or tabs, by replacing them with characters in CSS?

So turn

```
    $code = "x";
```

to

```
⋅⋅⋅⋅$code = "x";
```

or

```
    $code = "x";
```

to

```
→$code = "x";
```

( or something similar ).

Comment: CSS styles elements and their contents...what element are you proposing to select? Especially since text-nodes cannot be selected. So the answer is NO.

Comment: I don't think you could do this for multiple lines of code, but for a single line - such as the example you posted - it might be possible to **hack** this, but.... less useful. Would you be interested in a single line solution?

Comment: I'm aware of how CSS works, but since it's still getting some "magic" built into it, I was trying to figure out if there is less-known ways of dealing with things like this.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a font that displays spaces as dots, and tabs as tab characters.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot style a `textnode`. You can not style part of that, eigther, only real elements like `<p>`.

---

I know you don't want to use JS, but here is a possibility anyway for anyone else that might read this.

You can replace the characters with JS by using a regular expression that catches every form of whitespace and replaces it by characters, same for tabs.

```js
$('p').html($('p').html().replace(/&nbsp;/g,"_"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>&nbsp;&nbsp;test me </p>
```

```js
$('p').html($('p').html().replace(/ /g,"_"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>&nbsp;&nbsp;test me </p>
```

Comment: This is probably the only way to go, I was just trying to figure out is there is something already in CSS.